# Searching for data from one table in another table in t-sql (sql server2000)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have table A. This table does not have any PK, it just stores lots of rows, which can only be identified by combination of its column values.
There is procedure that takes data from table A, and from other tables, does proper matching/processing and feeds table B.
Now, how do I check if data from table A is correctly inserted into table B?
It is sql server 2000 so EXCEPT is not a solution.

Maybe some procedure that would include:

1. cursor would fetch rows from
   table A ,
2. do select on B (with proper
   column matching)
3. and then if matching row has been
   found (select returned some data)
   increase counter (number of properly
   propagated rows)
4. if no matching row was found put
   data we were looking for into
   temporary table (for later review)

Update:
Procedure that feeds table B doesn't put all rows from table A into table C. Additionally It also takes data from other table (let's call it C) and puts it into B (but also not all rows). I thought that maybe using one cursor to check B for data from A and then other cursor to check B for data from C would be good solution.

Comment: Post-update:  While I won't rule out that there are some situations that call for cursors, those are rare, and this is certainly NOT one of them.  There must be some criteria that lets you know why the rows from A did or did not make it to B.  You can modify either of the answers below to identify which rows should be in B but didn't make it.

Comment: And why don't you have PKs on every table? If you have a combination key you should at a minimum have a surrogate PK and a unique index on the combination of values that defines a record. If table A is just a staging table and is only used to store data for cleanup before moving to table b, maybe you could get away without the unique index (as maybe you haven't cleaned up the data to make it unique yet) but I put a PK on even those tables too as it is very helpful to be able to uniquely identify a record.

Comment: Table A and C are tables with data aggregated form other tables in database. Table B is base table for the view that is used to generate the reports. That is how it was designed, not my decision, and I'm not able to change it. I just need to struggle with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `NOT EXISTS` for rows that do not have a match according to your criteria

```
SELECT Columns
FROM TableA
Where NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM TableB
WHERE 1=1
AND TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column1
AND TableA.Column2 = TableB.Column2
AND TableA.Column3 = TableB.Column3
AND TableA.Column4 = TableB.Column4
)
```

You can do query for rows that have a match according to your criteria but do not have the rest of the data matching

```
SELECT Columns
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
    ON  TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column1
    AND TableA.Column2 = TableB.Column2
    AND TableA.Column3 = TableB.Column3
    AND TableA.Column4 = TableB.Column4
)
WHERE TableA.Column11 <> TableB.Column11
OR    TableA.Column12 <> TableB.Column12
OR    TableA.Column13 <> TableB.Column13
OR    TableA.Column14 <> TableB.Column14
```

Now that you have both sets of disconnected records, you can apply the necessary logic.

Most people here will give you SET based answers instead of CURSOR based answers. You will find a lot of material on StackOverflow regarding why not to use CURSORs.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a cursor?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) --or simply the list of columns
FROM A LEFT JOIN B
          ON A.col1 = B.col1
             AND A.col2 = B.Col2
             AND ....
WHERE A.col1 IS NULL AND A.col2 IS NULL
```

You may need to specify several columns in the WHERE clause to check for NULL if the possibility exists that several of those columns could be NULL.

This may not be very fast, so depending on your index structure you may want to do a count first to check and see if you have any unmatched rows, and then do the search for rows.